# How to sanitize request body using Micronaut before serialization?

Tags: security, filter, micronaut, sanitization

I'm trying to intercept all requests in order to sanitize the body. I've created a filter to do this, but this is not working since Micronaut had already serialized the request using *JsonContentProcessor*

My filter:

```
@Filter("/**")
public class RequestSanitizationFilter implements HttpServerFilter {

  private static final String SPECIAL_CHARACTERS = "()[]{}\\%/<>?$";

  @Override
  public int getOrder() {
    return ServerFilterPhase.FIRST.order();
  }

  @Override
  public Publisher<MutableHttpResponse<?>> doFilter(
      HttpRequest<?> request, ServerFilterChain chain) {

    String finalBody = request.getBody().toString();
    for (char i : SPECIAL_CHARACTERS.toCharArray()) {
      finalBody = finalBody.replace("" + i, "");
    }

    return Single.fromPublisher(chain.proceed(request.mutate().body(finalBody))).toFlowable();
  }
}
```

I could not find anything native that could help me with that. Is there any other way to do this before going to the controller?

Comment: What do you want to do during sanitization?

Comment: I want to remove specific special characters like this -> ()[]{}\\%/<>?$

Comment: I think that will prevent XML or JSON from being submitted.  Is that intentional?

Comment: nop, forget about these characters `[]{}`. Imagine that I wanna sanitize my json to remove something like these others `%/<>?$`

Answer (score 2):

Since Micronaut is built on Netty reading the body is done using asynchronous I/O in a non-blocking manner on demand based on the binding requirements of the controller which can change from method to method. Hence it is not possible to know or to in a manner that doesn't block read the body from a filter.

If you want to validate the body you can use a Netty channel handler:

```
package request.body.test;

import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

import io.micronaut.context.event.BeanCreatedEvent;
import io.micronaut.context.event.BeanCreatedEventListener;
import io.micronaut.core.annotation.Introspected;
import io.micronaut.core.annotation.Nullable;
import io.micronaut.http.HttpStatus;
import io.micronaut.http.annotation.Body;
import io.micronaut.http.annotation.Controller;
import io.micronaut.http.annotation.Post;
import io.micronaut.http.client.annotation.Client;
import io.micronaut.http.client.exceptions.HttpClientResponseException;
import io.micronaut.http.server.HttpServerConfiguration;
import io.micronaut.http.server.netty.NettyServerCustomizer;
import io.micronaut.runtime.EmbeddedApplication;
import io.micronaut.test.extensions.junit5.annotation.MicronautTest;
import io.netty.buffer.ByteBufUtil;
import io.netty.channel.Channel;
import io.netty.channel.ChannelHandlerContext;
import io.netty.channel.ChannelPipeline;
import io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler;
import io.netty.handler.codec.http.DefaultFullHttpResponse;
import io.netty.handler.codec.http.FullHttpRequest;
import io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpObjectAggregator;
import io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpResponseStatus;
import io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpVersion;
import jakarta.inject.Inject;
import jakarta.inject.Singleton;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import static io.micronaut.http.netty.channel.ChannelPipelineCustomizer.HANDLER_HTTP_STREAM;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertNotNull;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertThrows;

@MicronautTest
class RequestBodyTest {

    @Inject
    EmbeddedApplication<?> application;

    @Test
    void testInvalid(RequestBodySender sender) {
        HttpClientResponseException responseException = assertThrows(HttpClientResponseException.class, () ->
                sender.send(new Foo("test"))
        );
        assertEquals(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, responseException.getStatus());
    }

    @Test
    void testValid(RequestBodySender sender) {
        Foo foo = sender.send(new Foo("other"));
        assertNotNull(foo);
    }

    @Client("/test")
    interface RequestBodySender {
        @Post
        Foo send(@Body Foo foo);
    }
}


@Introspected
record Foo(String name) {}

@Controller("/test")
class TestController {
    @Post
    Foo receive(@Body Foo foo) {
        return foo;
    }
}

@Singleton
class BodyValidator implements BeanCreatedEventListener<NettyServerCustomizer.Registry>, NettyServerCustomizer {

    private static final String BODY_AGGREGATOR = "body-aggregator";
    private static final String BODY_VALIDATOR = "body-validator";
    private final Channel channel;
    private final HttpServerConfiguration serverConfiguration;

    public BodyValidator(@Nullable Channel channel, HttpServerConfiguration serverConfiguration) {
        this.channel = channel;
        this.serverConfiguration = serverConfiguration;
    }

    @Override
    public NettyServerCustomizer.Registry onCreated(BeanCreatedEvent<NettyServerCustomizer.Registry> event) {
        NettyServerCustomizer.Registry registry = event.getBean();
        registry.register(this);
        return registry;
    }

    @Override
    public NettyServerCustomizer specializeForChannel(Channel channel, ChannelRole role) {
        return new BodyValidator(channel, serverConfiguration);
    }


    @Override
    public void onStreamPipelineBuilt() {
        if (channel != null) {
            ChannelPipeline pipeline = channel.pipeline();
            pipeline.addBefore(HANDLER_HTTP_STREAM, BODY_AGGREGATOR, new HttpObjectAggregator((int) serverConfiguration.getMaxRequestSize()));
            pipeline.addAfter(BODY_AGGREGATOR, BODY_VALIDATOR, new SimpleChannelInboundHandler<FullHttpRequest>() {
                @Override
                protected void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, FullHttpRequest msg) {
                    byte[] bytes = ByteBufUtil.getBytes(msg.content());
                    // validate bytes
                    String s = new String(bytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
                    if (s.contains("test")) {
                        ctx.writeAndFlush(
                            new DefaultFullHttpResponse(HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1, new HttpResponseStatus(HttpResponseStatus.BAD_REQUEST.code(), "Request failed validation"))
                        ).addListener(listener -> channel.close());
                    } else {
                        ctx.fireChannelRead(msg);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```